# How to cross-compile Rust code for the Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: linux, rust, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile Rust code on my 64-bit x86 laptop to run on the Raspberry Pi Zero W. I installed the `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` toolchain using Rustup, but when I run `cargo build --target arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`, I get this error:

> Internal error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` installed?

I tried to install the [`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` package from AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc/), but that kept failing because of some sort of GPG key error, so I just decided to make my own cross-compiler using crosstool-ng.

I tried to point Cargo at my newly built cross-compiler using a `~/.cargo/config` file:

```
[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "/home/ibi/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```

But Cargo seems to be ignoring this and giving me the same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It worked when I set an environment variable:

```sh
$ export CC="/home/ibi/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```